# Maximum set cover with non-overlap

Tags: optimization, np-complete, reference-request, sets, set-cover

Let the universe be the set $U$ and a set of subsets $S$ be such that $\cup_{s \in S} s = U$. I am interested in computing the longest sequence of sets $s_1, ..., s_k$ such that:

1. $s_i \in S$ $\forall i \in [k]$
2. $s_i \not\subseteq \cup_{j=1}^{i-1} s_j$ (so each $s_i$ adds at least one new element on top of the existing $i-1$ sets)

Is there a polynomial time algorithm that can compute this longest sequence of sets given a $(U, S)$ instance? Or is this known to be hard (a reference paper on this would be much appreciated)?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/159525/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52704/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).